# What is the mathematical meaning of the following sentence

Tags: real-analysis, functions

What is the mathematical meaning of the following sentence:

The function $f(x)$ is **non-decreasing** as $x$ **decreases** to $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means if $$0<x_1<x_2$$ then $$f(x_1)\ge f(x_2)$$

Answer (score 2):

The statement seems poorly stated.

Perhaps it means that there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $f$ is non-decreasing on the interval $(0,\epsilon)$.